# Parametrization of oriented circle

Tags: calculus

I have noticed this pattern in a few questions and was wondering if it was a general rule?

When parametrizing a circle or radius 1 if the circle is clockwise is the parametrization always

$r=sin(t)i+cos(t)j$

and counterclockwise always
$r=cos(t)i+sin(t)j$

Comment: Why you use j and I, why not just x an y? The direction is determined by the values of t and the functions used. draw it - may be with the aid of GeoGebra.

Comment: r =  -(sin t)i + (cos t)j starts at the same point.